# Parse Received Message in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-chatbot

I am coding a Facebook Messenger ChatBot with Ruby on Rails.

I create a database for responses. If message exist in my database it replies, else reply as "Sorry not found."

```
  ....
  def analysis(sender, text)

    message = Message.where(:recieved => text).first
    if message
      reply = message.reply
    else
      reply = "Sorry not found"
    end
    send_message(sender,reply)
  end
  ....
```

I want to add regex match like conditions. Like this: If message contains "this" word. reply with "that".

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `include?`, that's slightly faster than applying regex `'A string that contains bla'.include?('bla') ? do_this : do_another_thing`

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". What have you tried? Show us the minimum code necessary to demonstrate your attempt to solve this, and describe what it is not doing correctly. Without that you're asking us to write code for you, or to write a tutorial, both of which are off topic. I'd recommend learning about `case`/`when` and how regular expressions work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring indexing:

```
definite_article = message.reply['this'] ? 'that' : 'this'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i get what is your intention, but you either could use `gsub` method [docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub/%22gsub%20docs%22) if you want to replace occurrences of given patterns in responses.

Or simply use conditional statements to match given regexs like:

```
  if /this/.match(message.reply)
     reply = 'that'
```